# Rails 4: the right way to initialize hash table from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

my first question, be gentle :-)

I have a rails application using pieces of text from a database (table basically contains a short key k and the corresponding text; sort of like i18n, but for reasons out of scope here I don't want to use that right now). Made a small helper function for the views to get the matching text by key, along the lines of "Text.find_by k: x". Hell of a database load but allowing the texts to be changed dynamically by a CMS.

But since it turned out that the texts do rarely change, I wanted to preload the whole table into a hash instead. Since I'm not sure where to put such initialization stuff, and also because I thought lazy loading might be cool, here is what I did (simplified):

```
module MainHelper
...
@@items = nil

def getText(x)
  initItems if !@@items
  @@items[x]
end

private

def initItems
  @@items = {}
  Text.all.each {|t| @@items[t.k] = t.text}  #load from model
end
```

Which seems to work great. But since I am quite a newbie here, I wonder if anybody thinks there is a better solution, or a solution that is more "the rails way"? Any comments highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is pretty cool. I'd be more likely to make a method `items` that memoizes the items, as opposed to an explicit `initItems` method.  That would be the more conventional solution.

Use `pluck` to get only the fields in the table that you need... it'll make the SQL call more efficient.

because `pluck` in this case returns an array of two-element arrays, it's easy to use the `to_h` method to convert it into a hash.

(also, convention is to use snake_case for method names)

```
module MainHelper
  ...
  @@items = nil

  def get_text(x)
    items[x]
  end

  private

  def items
    @@items ||= Text.pluck(:k,:text).to_h  #load from model
  end

end
```